# Google compute engine cannot select different machine type

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've used Google compute engine before and I was able to select shared CPUs. But when I login today and click the machine type, the drop down list is empty (as attached). I tried to switch to different accounts and browsers but still the same.

May I know if anyone else has this problem also? Any ways I can bypass the drop down list?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is a known issue. You can refer to my answer on [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/767113/google-compute-engine-quickstart/767346#767346).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I saw you were the one who answer that post also, may I know the possible time it can be resolved? I believe this bug exists for over 2 weeks, is it a simple UI problem or something much harder to resolve? Thank you

Comment: engineering has pushed an update and this issue should be resolved by the end of the day today.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Good luck and we support Google!